# Parsing JSON with TCL

Tags: json, tcl

Using TCL does anyone know how to parse json that contain an array? The first dict key is entries but I cannot figure out how to get the values array; I need Person ID, Full Name and Company

```
{
    "entries": [
        {
            "values": {
                "Person ID": "PPL000000087294",
                "Full Name": "Beth Woltmann",
                "Company": "SWIFT TEST COMPANY"
            },
            "_links": {
                "self": [{
                    "href": "http://da3u-gen-swt-app001.dalab.syniverse.com:8008/api/arsys/v1/entry/CTM:People/PPL000000087294"
                }]
            }
        }, {
            "values": {
                "Person ID": "PPL000000010665",
                "Full Name": "Elizabeth Woltmann",
                "Company": "SYNIVERSE TECHNOLOGIES, INC."
            },
            "_links": {
                "self": [{
                    "href": "http://da3u-gen-swt-app001.dalab.syniverse.com:8008/api/arsys/v1/entry/CTM:People/PPL000000010665"
                }]
            }
        }, {
            "values": {
                "Person ID": "PPL000000134257",
                "Full Name": "Elizabeth Woltmann",
                "Company": "SYNIVERSE TECHNOLOGIES, INC."
            },
            "_links": {
                "self": [{
                    "href": "http://da3u-gen-swt-app001.dalab.syniverse.com:8008/api/arsys/v1/entry/CTM:People/PPL000000134257"
                }]
            }
        }
    ],
    "_links": {
        "self": [{
            "href": "http://da3u-gen-swt-app001.dalab.syniverse.com:8008/api/arsys/v1/entry/CTM:People?fields=values%28Person%20ID,Full%20Name,Company%29&q=%27Internet%20E-mail%27=%22elizabeth.woltmann@syniverse.com%22AND%27Profile%20Status%27=%22Enabled%22"
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Do take a look at the [wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/JSON) which shows up first when googling "tcl json parse". I think you could have obtained at least some insight if you had checked there first.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [tcllib json package](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/json/json.md) makes it easy:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
package require json

set data [::json::json2dict $yourjson]
foreach entry [dict get $data entries] {
  set id [dict get $entry values "Person ID"]
  set name [dict get $entry values "Full Name"]
  set company [dict get $entry values Company]
  puts "$id\t$name\t$company"
}
```

Output:

```
PPL000000087294 Beth Woltmann   SWIFT TEST COMPANY
PPL000000010665 Elizabeth Woltmann      SYNIVERSE TECHNOLOGIES, INC.
PPL000000134257 Elizabeth Woltmann      SYNIVERSE TECHNOLOGIES, INC.
```